# Removing uninteded div around input box created by Bootstrap using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I am trying to create a slider using Jquery and store the input in a `<input type="text" readonly>`. 
This works when i am just placing the input type in the body of the html page, but when i place it in a popup-window div. It then creates an extra div around the input tag that (I guess?) inherits the css of the popup-window div. And thus having a real bulky border around itself.

I noticed the created div when inspecting the elements in Chrome. 
Is there anyway to either make so Jquery doesnt create the unecessary div or atleast remove the inherited css from it and make it invisible.

The Html:

```
<span style='position:absolute; bottom:5px; left:15px;'>
            <a href="#vote" id="vote-button" data-rel="popup" 
                class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" 
                data-position-to="window"
                data-transition="fade">
                Vote
            </a>
        </span>
    <div data-role="popup" id="vote" style="width:300px; margin:auto; overflow:none;" class="ui-content">

                <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right"></a>

                    <br>
                    <button href="#main" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all" style="position:relative; width:100%; margin:0 auto">Skicka</button>
        <p>
          <label for="amount"></label>
          <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        </p>
    </div>
```

The Javascript/jQuery:

```
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
  value:100,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  step: 50,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

});

I followed this example for the sliders:
https://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax

 And this example for the popup window: [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_popups.asp)


Codepen.io: [Error case](http://codepen.io/Redstream/pen/mVGmYe)

Cheers

Comment: Since you know the container from development tool, why don't you just remove or decrease the border around it in your CSS code using "!important" tag? It should work. By the way, It is better to create an example in codepen.io and share it in your question. This way, people can easily look into it and find it a solution.

Comment: @zeropoint if you use too many `!important`'s it might mean your css ordering isn't optimal. I personally always try to avoid it if possible, to me it's a lazy solution.

Comment: I agree with you that it is not a good practice, however, if you look into bootstrap CSS files, you see so many "!important". To override on those, you need to have it in your styling as well.

Comment: The thing is that the div isnt created before the page is loaded and thus have no id or class, so I do not know how to change it or its style in anyway. Thanks for the codepen.io tip, never used that before will definatly look into it.

Comment: you just need to know a class or id associated to that div. typically, those elements have a particular class and/or id which is assigned by bootstrap. Then, you just need to change its style in your CSS file. Whenever the div pop out, your CSS code will be applied to it.

Comment: @zeropoint The div doesnt have any id when inspecting it in the browser, is there any other way to find it?

Comment: how about a particular class? can you just create an example with the same issue in codepen.io? That would same a lot of our time.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I Will do that and add to the question. The class is "ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" And i dont think that would only affect this div.

Comment: I have created a html page that gets the error at codepen.io : [link](http://codepen.io/Redstream/pen/mVGmYe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Found a better way to do it, check it out [HERE on CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/JGaJJP):

```
$("#vote-button").click(function() {
     $("#vote").find(".ui-input-text").remove(); 
})
```

This will completely remove the div wrapped around your input box without any pain.

---

Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/EPeXyM).

The way that I solved is to first remove all classes from the div element wrapped around your input box like this:

```
  $("#vote-button").click(function() {

       $("#vote").find(".ui-input-text").removeClass("ui-body-inherit").removeClass("ui-corner-all").removeClass("ui-shadow-inset").removeClass("ui-input-text");

   })
```

Then, when you click on the input box, Bootstrap adds a new class which is `ui-focus`. There is two way to do it. First one is with jQuery:

```
$("#amount").click(function() {
   if ($(this).closest("div").hasClass("ui-focus")) {
         $(this).closest("div").removeClass("ui-focus");
   }
})
```

It works, however it shows the box-shadow for a short amount of time and goes away fast. The other approach is to use CSS as this:

```
.ui-focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

This approach is dangerous because it will mess up with all other elements which uses this class to shine when clicked and activated.

Comment: check out the updated approach. much better without changing any original bootstrap CSS and styles.

Comment: Thank you! This  solved the main problem. The only fallback is that it seems like there still is a new line before the value, is there any way to get rid of that effect?

Comment: There is no line before the value. There is only slight margin-bottom on the label before value.

Comment: My bad, missed that. Thanks once again!